# How to grab all index values from a dictionary in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, dictionary

I am trying to  read the values for all indexes in the dictionary. I can only grab one index at a time.

```
var monster: Monster!

monster.moves![0]["move_id"] as? Int ?? 0
```

That lets me grab the first item in the index. But I'm reading from a sqlite database and need to match values.

```
for user in try! db.prepare(Table("moves").where(id == (monster.moves![0]["move_id"] as? Int ?? 0) && damage_class == (monster.moves![0]["move_id"] as? Int ?? 0))) { }
```

It will only check if the id matches the monster.moves! at the first index, instead of checking all of them. I need to grab the values where `move_id` equals a certain number. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the values from a dictionary in this way.

```
for value in yourDictionary.values.array {
    print("\(value)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that this may need some tweaking since I don't have much of your code to go off of:

```
let monsterArray = monster.values.filter { $0["move_id"] == id && $0["move_id"] == damage_class }
```

In English, this takes your `monster` dictionary, accesses the arrays of all `values` it contains, and then filters based on what is specified in the `{ }` brackets. The results will then be saved in the `monsterArray` constant.

With the `monsterArray`, you can then perform whatever action you need against just those values.

Using this approach will also be much faster than a `for` loop since you will not need to iterate through every possible value.

Answer (score 0):

try this

if moves property in your Monster object is not NSArray type, then convert it into NSArray type

```
if let movesArray : NSArray =  monster.moves as! NSArray
{
  let idsArray = movesArray.valueForKey("move_id") as! [Int] // change it to your required type array
}
```

there you go now you have move ids in `idsArray`, now you can do what ever you want to do with those ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need index for all dictionary's value.Please try it. i Hope it's work

```
for index in 0...monster.moves.count-1{

   for user in try! db.prepare(Table("moves").where(id == (monster.moves![index]["move_id"] as? Int ?? 0) && damage_class == (monster.moves![index]["move_id"] as? Int ?? 0))) 
   { 
      //Whatever you want to do
   }
}
```